# jsonp backbon fetch collection

Tags: backbone.js, collections, jsonp, fetch

this is my situation

```
var player = new Backbone.Model.extend({});
    var QuerySolarModel = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: player,

        url : function (){
            return myurl";
            },
       });

    this.list = new QuerySolarModel();
    this.list.filter= filter;
            this.list.fetch({
            dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function(){
            console.log('success');
        },
        error: function(data, response) {
               console.log("errore ");
            }
    }).complete(function () {alert("done");});
    console.log('la lista dovrebbe essere '+this.list);
```

I've to fetch a collection by a external url the answer of the url is

```
    {
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":1,
    "params":{
      "indent":"true",
      "q":"FULLNAME:MINO",
      "wt":"json"}},
  "response":{"numFound":18,"start":0,"docs":[
      {
        "id":"2",
        "PHYSICAL_CUSTOMER_DATA_ID":"5",
        "CONTRACT_IDENTITY":"0000000002",
        "STATUS_ID":"3",
        "STATUS_DESC":"Suspended",
        "FULLNAME":"MINO MAX",
        "GAME_ACCOUNT_ID":"1000000038",
        "ADDRESS":"VIA ROMA_1 VIA ROMA_2 VIA ROMA_3",
        "EMAIL":["l.ghionna@mail.it",
          "3475061120"],
        "_version_":1432013050215399424},
      {
        "id":"3",
        "PHYSICAL_CUSTOMER_DATA_ID":"6",
        "CONTRACT_IDENTITY":"0000000003",
        "FULLNAME":"MINO MAX",
        "GAME_ACCOUNT_ID":"1000000045",
        "ADDRESS":"VIA ROMA_1 VIA ROMA_2 VIA ROMA_3",
        "EMAIL":["3475061120",
          "l.ghionna@mail.it"],
        "_version_":1432013050244759552}]
  }}
```

i want to make a collection of model for every "player"
but the browser answer to me:

Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/plain: "myurl". jquery.js:8169

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : select:1

where i'm mistaking??

EDIT:
i understood why it's not working,
whew you use a jsnop it have to wrap by callback({your json}) mmm  now what i can do?

Comment: Are you certain the endpoint you're calling supports returning jsonp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove `dataType: "jsonp"` from options.

Also your code is not valid -> `return myurl";`

Comment: if don't use dataType jsonp, the i've problem of cross domain!,
and myurl is a url... http://10.30.... lol